# Single Controller to support multiple model attribute objects

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I will explain my scenario shortly. I have two forms in different jsps

A. jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editForm" action="tableEditor/saveTable.do">
 <form:input path="name">
</form:form>
```

B.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="editForm" action="tableEditor/saveTable.do">
 <form:input path="id">
</form:form>
```

correspondingly i have Model Classes

```
public class Model1{
   String name;
}

public class Model2{
   String id;
}
```

I would like to have one controller method support this two forms with `BindingResult` validations

Not like the below one

```
public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute("editForm") Model1 edit, BindingResult result) {

}
```

After some research i found this one.
[Spring - adding BindingResult to newly created model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052752/spring-adding-bindingresult-to-newly-created-model-attribute)

So Can i design someThing like the following or any other better ideas?

```
public String addCustomer(Model model) {
      BindingResult errors = null;
      if(someCondition){      
        Model model1 = model.asMap().getAttribute("editForm");
        if (!model1 .validate()) {
            errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(model1, "editForm");
            errors.reject("invalid operation");
            model.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "editForm", errors);
        }
      }
  else{
    Model model2 = model.asMap().getAttribute("editForm");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why? Just make two methods.

Comment: I have like 19 models after from the model type...the other operation comes after will be like simple crud operation...It will be like N number of request controllers